# Using ng-repeat with markers in ngMap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-map, angularjs-google-maps

I want to use [ngMap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to add Google Maps to my app.

The demos are "static" in the sense that they have only hard coded HTML. I want my code to be "dynamic" in the sense that it will periodically ask a server to look in its database and return me a bunch of coordinates to plot, which will change with time. I hope that that is clear; if not, please ask for more detail.

I modified the [ngmap markers demo](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/marker.html) to generate some random lat/long coordinates every two seconds (rather than going to my server, as my final app will). Please see [the Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcRYfXZa6sSteU61RCBA?p=preview).

There are no errors in the console, and it seems that ngMap is trying to add my markers, as I see a lot of this sort of thing in the console ...

```
adding marker with options,  
Object {ngRepeat: "myMarker in markers", position: O}
clickable: true
ngRepeat: "myMarker in markers"
position: O
A: 103.96749299999999
k: 1.387454
__proto__: O
visible: true
__proto__: Object
```

where K and A are the Lat/Long as I expect them to be.

BUT ... I don't see any markers on the map. What am I doing wrong?

---

[Update] An excellent answer, for which I gladly awarded a bounty afterwards. For anyone else reading this and wishing to use ngMap as @allenhwkim said in another stackoverflow question and, I think, on his blog, ngMap just creates the map for you & after that you manipulate it with the standard Google Maps API.

For instance, just before looping to add the markers, I declared
`var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` and in the loop, after adding the marker to the map, I `bounds.extend(latlng);` and, finally, after the loop, I

```
var centre = bounds.getCenter();  
$scope.map.setCenter(centre);
```

I forked the answer and created [a new Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZATMU5hsSNLNUp37wPj?p=preview) to show this. Not the world's most useful functionality, but the point is just to show how to use `$scope.map` with the Google Maps API. Thanks again, Allen, for ngMap.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answer is here

http://plnkr.co/edit/Widr0o?p=preview

Please remember that ngMap is not replacing Google Maps V3 API.

Let me know if you have further questions.

The following is code block of the controller.

```
// $scope.map .. this exists after the map is initialized
var markers = [];
for (var i=0; i<8 ; i++) {
  markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: "Hi marker " + i
  })
}
$scope.GenerateMapMarkers = function() {
  $scope.date = Date(); // Just to show that we are updating

  var numMarkers = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 4;  // betwween 4 & 8 of them
  for (i = 0; i < numMarkers; i++) {
    var lat =   1.280095 + (Math.random()/100);
    var lng = 103.850949 + (Math.random()/100);
    // You need to set markers according to google api instruction
    // you don't need to learn ngMap, but you need to learn google map api v3
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    markers[i].setPosition(latlng);
    markers[i].setMap($scope.map)
  }      

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.GenerateMapMarkers(); 
  }, 2000);  // update every 2 seconds
};  

$scope.GenerateMapMarkers();
```

Comment: +1, the answer, and a 200 point bonus tomorrow!! Thanks you so much, Allen. Your ngMap seems to be perfect for me. I just want to get a fixed size map drawn and then (use the Goggle Maps API to) add and move Markers (and call SetBounds so that the map encompasses them), change the Marker tooltips, draw PolyLines, etc. This is an excellent toolkit.  Btw, perhaps you ought to consider adding this to your examples. with a few words on your blog page for people like me who want to update "dynamic" maps.

Comment: @Mawg, thanks for your extra points(You shouldn't have). As you said, I added dynamic markers as an example file, and hopefully it's useful for many.

Comment: Ah, yes, https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/examples/dynamic_markers.html  I also forked your Plunk to  show how to use the Google Maps API after ngMap creates the map. I had tried a few solutions for Angulr Google Maps but couldn't get any to work. Then I found ngMap and it is everything that I could wish for. Thanks!

Comment: @allenhwkim your plunker is  not working it can't find the ngMap module

Comment: @allenhwkim there is one thing more. Can you tell me how can I animate a marker when I click on a div. for example I have div with a  title if I click on it the marker starts bouncing or some other kind of animation starts working

Comment: @allenhwkim the plunker is still not working it can't include the ngmap modeule

Comment: @allenhwkim there is just one thing else that I would like to know and it that where is the $scope.map object

Comment: @allenhwkim Thanks for the solution. But there is a problem with the plunkr. The link used for ngmap.min.js is not working. I've edited it. This is working fine. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/Widr0o?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

Why not do something like

```
<map zoom="2" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
  <marker position="{{destination.position}}" ng-repeat="destination in destinations"></marker>
</map>
```

If you asking for ng-repeat that would work. And you would populate the destinations with a simple http call to your backend:

```
$http.get(url + '/destinations', config).success(function (data) {
  if (data != null && data.total > 0) {
      $scope.destinations = data.destinations;
  } else {
      $scope.destinations = []
  }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.. I was trying the same thing with Polygons instead of markers, and the polygons don't show up.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does one show up? Strip down the code and see when it stops working, otherwise I can't really help much :)

Comment: No worries, @allenhwkim's answer worked for me. This feels cleaner though, so I gave it a shot.

Comment: This solution will also work. The difference is the performance. When we use ng-repeat, it will also update DOM, and sometimes updating DOM is not necessary and updating DOM is quite expensive.