# How to display google marker on map Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `ng-map` [library](http://ngmap.github.io/events.html#/event-simple#event-simple) for Angular.
I try to show one or some markers on map.
I have read tutorial and can display it via directive `market` in template HTML like as:

```
<marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>
```

But how I can do it from controller Angular if there are some markers map?

Comment: I found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372161/using-ng-repeat-with-markers-in-ngmap

Comment: All links from answers was deleted also first example does not work, only second